# Form.IO Renderer Angular 8 Load Form from variable

Tags: formio

I cannot get the form to render when passing the JSON string as a variable. If I paste the string into the HTML it works fine. Very confused.
My HTML:

```
<formio [form]="form" (submit)="onSubmit($event)"></formio>
```

I preload the JSON and pull from route data. My component:

```
  export class FormIOViewerComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }
  form:string='';
  onSubmit(submission: any) {
    console.log(submission); 
  }
  ngOnInit() {    
    this.form=this.route.snapshot.data.Fields;
    console.log(this.form)
  }
}
```

The JSON string prints to console before the error, and again I can copy and paste the JSON string printed from the console into the HTML and it displays fine. The error seen in Chrome:

```
form-ioviewer.component.html:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
at new Formio (Formio.js:213)
at Form.setForm (Form.js:185)
at new Form (Form.js:106)
at FormioComponent.push../node_modules/angular-formio/FormioBaseComponent.js.FormioBaseComponent.createRenderer (FormioBaseComponent.js:90)
at FormioComponent.push../node_modules/angular-formio/FormioBaseComponent.js.FormioBaseComponent.setForm (FormioBaseComponent.js:111)
at FormioBaseComponent.js:402
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:359)
at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:124)
at NgZone.runOutsideAngular (core.js:39572)
at FormioComponent.push../node_modules/angular-formio/FormioBaseComponent.js.FormioBaseComponent.ngOnChanges (FormioBaseComponent.js:398)
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it won't except a JSON string, it MUST be a object. Something like:

```
export class formIO {
    title:string;
    name:string
    components: string[]
  }
```

Then pass the object to the form, not the string.